# An error occurred while entries were being updated.

Tags: sql, entity-framework

First of all, Sorry for the bad english. 
I'm working on a university project with EF 4.0. Everytime i want to delete an entity item from the collection i get the error : "An error occurred while entries were being updated."
I have foreign keys.

I can't post images because i justa have 1 point of rep, so i can't show you de diagramas.

```
    private void Elimina_Pais_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int IdPaisABorrar = ((Pais)Tabla_Paises_DataGrid.SelectedItem).Id;

        MundialEntities db = new MundialEntities();

        Pais PaisABorrar = db.Paises.Single(p => p.Id == IdPaisABorrar);
        if(PaisABorrar != null)
        db.Paises.Remove(PaisABorrar);
        db.SaveChanges();            
        UpdatePaises();

    }
```

Inner Exception {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_Pais_Visita\". The conflict occurred in database \"Mundial\", table \"dbo.Partido\", column 'IdVisita'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
Thank You very Much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to delete (remove) a record that is still being used in another table.  So unless  [cascade delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete) can be setup on this record type, you will need to remove the other record/s at the sametime or before.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can you cascade delete in your migration table or you can load the entities to delete them

Something like (believing that you have some table called as Visita (replace it with your table name)

```
Pais PaisABorrar = db.Paises
                     .Include(p => p.Visita)
                     .Single(p => p.Id == IdPaisABorrar);
```

The statement Include(p => p.Visita) will load all the related entries and then they will be deleted by call db.Paises.Remove(PaisABorrar);

NOTE: If this had helped you then dont forgot to vote it up and mark it as answer